# Chrome extension: Extension button appears in extensions area but JS doesn't execute on click?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm dabbling a bit in making a chrome extension, and I followed the guide here (https://thoughtbot.com/blog/how-to-make-a-chrome-extension), which worked as expected. However, now that I'm changing it to work on other sites, it doesn't execute anything upon clicking the button. I feel like it's something obvious, but I don't know what.

Code:

manifest:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "extension_name",
  "version": "0.1",

  "description": "extension_description",
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "declarativeContent",
    "storage",
    "https://*/*",
    "http://*/*"
  ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },

  "page_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  }
}
```

Popup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <button id="myButton">Scan</button>
  </body>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

Popup JS

```
'use strict';
let myBtn = document.getElementById('myButton');
peble.onclick = (element) => {
    console.log("You have hit the button.");
};
```

Background JS

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
    chrome.storage.sync.set({color: '#3aa757'}, function() {
        console.log('Active.');
    });
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
        chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
            conditions: [
                new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                    pageUrl: {hostEquals: 'www.youtube.com'},
                })
            ],
            actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.ShowPageAction()]
      }]);
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not trying to add a new URL - I'm trying to get it to work for the existing url. Sorry if I was clear on that!

Comment: YouTube is the site I'm making the extension for. What I'm saying is that the button does nothing on YouTube when I press it. It should log to console, but doesn't.

Comment: The popup is a separate window so it has its own console. Right-click inside the popup, then click inspect.

Comment: Ok, does it have access to the DOM of the page?

Comment: No, see [How to access the webpage DOM rather than the extension page DOM?](//stackoverflow.com/a/4532567)

Answer (score 0):

Per wOxxOm - The button has it's own html space - it isn't outputting to the same DOM console as the page.